# Convert selected elements in data frame from float to integer unsuccessful

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a list of elements in the dataframe called "GDP" from floating to integers. The cells that I want to convert are specified in GDP.iloc[4,-10]. I have tried the following methods:

1. for x in GDP.iloc[4,-10:]:
   pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='signed')
2. GDP.iloc[4,-10:]=GDP.iloc[4,-10:].astype(int)
3. GDP.iloc[4,-10:]=int(GDP.iloc[4,-10:])

However, none of them seem to be working in converting the float to integers. No errors appear for methods 1 and 2 but for option 3, the following error appears:
TypeError: cannot convert the series to

The data can be found here: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD

```
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv',header=None)
```

Method 1

```
for x in GDP.iloc[4,-10:]: 
   pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='signed')
```

Method 2:

```
GDP.iloc[4,-10:]=GDP.iloc[4,-10:].astype(int)
```

Method 3:

```
GDP.iloc[4,-10:]=int(GDP.iloc[4,-10:])
```

Can someone help me out? Much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGuDj.png)

Comment: Data types in a Pandas dataframe are for the entire Column and not just for a single value in a Column, you can turn it from (e.g 3.4 to 3.0 in float) but if you want it as 3 and Integer, you will need to convert entire column to integer

Comment: In a series or a dataframe, the data type is casted to the entire column. If you have one string in a column of 10 other floats, the  entire column will be an object column

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify: are you using `pandas`?  If so - add portion of `GDP` (which I assume is `pandas.DataFrame`) in your question. E.g. `GDP.head()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `astype(np.int64)` to convert to int

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# df.head()
df = df.fillna('custom_none_values')
# df.head()
df = df[df['1960'] != 'custom_none_values']
df['1960'] = df['1960'].astype(np.int64)
df.head()
```

[image]